# SATA drive problems with two SIL RAID cards

Tags: linux, raid, sata, irq

I've just put a second SiI 3114 SATARaid card in my home server so that I could add
another pair of SATA drives and increase my storage space.  Annoyingly, it
doesn't seem to work:

```
[   32.816030] ata5: lost interrupt (Status 0x0)
[   32.816072] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   32.816091] ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 4096
in
[   32.816094]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4
(timeout)
[   32.816101] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[   32.816117] ata5: hard resetting link
[   33.136082] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[   36.060940] irq 18: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[   36.060949] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.31-20-generic #58-Ubuntu
[   36.060954] Call Trace:
[   36.060977]  [] ? printk+0x18/0x1c
[   36.060997]  [] __report_bad_irq+0x27/0x90
[   36.061005]  [] note_interrupt+0x150/0x190
[   36.061011]  [] handle_fasteoi_irq+0xac/0xd0
[   36.061023]  [] handle_irq+0x18/0x30
[   36.061029]  [] do_IRQ+0x47/0xc0
[   36.061042]  [] ? irq_exit+0x50/0x70
[   36.061058]  [] ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x57/0x90
[   36.061065]  [] common_interrupt+0x30/0x40
[   36.061075]  [] ? native_safe_halt+0x5/0x10
[   36.061082]  [] default_idle+0x46/0xd0
[   36.061088]  [] cpu_idle+0x8c/0xd0
[   36.061103]  [] rest_init+0x55/0x60
[   36.061111]  [] start_kernel+0x2e6/0x2ec
[   36.061117]  [] ? unknown_bootoption+0x0/0x19e
[   36.061133]  [] i386_start_kernel+0x7c/0x83
[   36.061137] handlers:
[   36.061139] [] (sil_interrupt+0x0/0xb0)
[   36.061151] Disabling IRQ #18
[   38.136014] ata5: hard resetting link
[   38.456022] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[   43.456013] ata5: hard resetting link
[   43.776022] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[   43.776035] ata5.00: disabled
[   43.776055] ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[   43.776074] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK
driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   43.776082] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current]
[descriptor]
[   43.776092] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[   43.776097]         72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[   43.776112]         00 00 00 00 
[   43.776118] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[   43.776127] end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0
[   43.776136] Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 0
[   43.776170] ata5: EH complete
[   43.776187] ata5.00: detaching (SCSI 4:0:0:0)
```

```
root@core:~# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       
  0:         47   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          8   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  6:          3   IO-APIC-edge      floppy
  7:          0   IO-APIC-edge      parport0
  8:          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 14:      53069   IO-APIC-edge      pata_sis
 15:      53004   IO-APIC-edge      pata_sis
 17:     112265   IO-APIC-fasteoi   sata_sil
 18:     200002   IO-APIC-fasteoi   sata_sil, SiS SI7012
 19:     111140   IO-APIC-fasteoi   eth0
 20:          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ohci_hcd:usb2
 21:          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ohci_hcd:usb3
 23:          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
NMI:          0   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:    6650492   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0   Spurious interrupts
CNT:          0   Performance counter interrupts
PND:          0   Performance pending work
RES:          0   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:          0   Function call interrupts
TLB:          0   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:        160   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
root@core:~# lspci | grep Raid
00:09.0 RAID bus controller: Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3114 [SATALink/SATARaid] Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
00:0a.0 RAID bus controller: Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3114 [SATALink/SATARaid] Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
root@core:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Release:        9.10
Codename:       karmic
root@core:~# uname -a
Linux core.topper.me.uk 2.6.31-20-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 12 05:23:09 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried a combination of different kernel options (irqpoll, noapic, noacpi,
pci=noapic) all to no avail.  Does anyone have any bright ideas about how I
can go about making this work?

Swapping PCI cards around isn't an option as there are only two slots in this motherboard (an ASRock K7S41GX).  The BIOS doesn't look to have too much in the way of configuration options regarding IRQ usage.

Plan B is to ditch this server completely and buy a new QNAP for these drives to go in, but I was hoping to avoid doing this right now.

Answer (score 1):

On someone else's suggestion I tried swapping the two PCI cards around in the motherboard.  This has (a little annoyingly) seemed to work - can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there was just a touch of corrosion on the socket contacts on the motherboard. I've had this happen to me many times, and a common cure is to simply unplug/replug the offending device. (Powered off, of course.) This is especially common in equipment which is exposed to humidity and dust. If you have continued problems, try using a product such as [Deoxit](http://store.caig.com/s.nl/sc.2/category.188/.f) on the contacts. I've used this when working on 30 year old radar sets to good effect.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather speculation on my part, but anyway: the BIOS could be assigning the cards different (random) IRQs if it sees a new card in slot. As you swapped the cards, it is possible that it changed the assigned IRQs and resolved IRQ conflict this way.